# Moodle mdl_file table, check if a file is deleted

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I am trying to get images & videos added in course summary from mdl_files table using below query.

```
select filename from {files} where contextid= :contextid and component = :component and filearea = :filearea and (filename is not null or filename != '') and (source is not null or source != '') order by timemodified desc limit 1
```

Everything works fine. But the problem is how can I know if a file is deleted from the editor? Above query returns the file even after it is deleted from the editor and saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File details will get deleted from the mdl_files table only when it is deleted by clicking on the 'Manage files' button on the editor.

Comment: That is not answering your own question asking how to check if a file is deleted with a database query.

Comment: @FMCorz        File will remain on the table until we delete it through 'Manage files' button. So we cannot know it through query.

Comment: I see. I suppose you could automate that by parsing the content of the summary itself, which is what "Manage files" does to display the list of unused files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you want to retrieve the image as it's been uploaded in the editor you have to use the files which are stored under `component = user, filearea = draft`. Those files are transient and only stored during the content edition, they are migrated upon saving (see below). Though, in order to do this efficiently, you'll also have to know the `draftitemid`.

If what you're interested in is to get the summary files of a course, then you must search in `component = course, filearea = overviewfiles`. Those records will only be affected after the user saves any changes, so this will always represent what all visitors see.